# Monaco Editor: Fold and unfold specific part of the code

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco, react-monaco-editor

I'm using monaco-editor for educational purposes about one topic.

I was trying to fold and unfold specific part of the code to let the user understand what each part of the code do.

For example, I would like to fold all the functions but one and visualize the specific documentation for that function. And so far and so on for all the functions in the code.

They can have different levels of depth.

I'm using this function here but seems to not work. I think I'm not using it properly.

```js
editorRef.current.editor.trigger('fold', 'editor.foldAll');
editor.trigger('unfold', 'editor.unfold', {
  levels: 4,
  direction: 'down',
  selectionLines: [106, 123, 133],
});
```

Can someone help me?

I expect that monaco-editor reveal the actual function but instead just unfold one level in deepth

Answer (score 0):

In older version of monaco editor arguments were not passed to actions

[image]

It should be fixed here https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/2547

Until that fix you can position cursor of an editor to the block of code you want to fold/unfold and trigger an action without arguments, so editor will use cursor position to identify which block to fold